# Why my regular expression function `string.test("abc")` doesn't work?

Tags: regex, function

Why does my regular expression function don't work? Is there a special operator or object?

```
function(string){
    console.log(string.test("abc"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

test() method is not available on string.But is is available on regular expression.So please check what is your parameter in this case.

you can try it on console a = /[a-z]/ , a.test('abc') and the output will be true